# Does Go support real-time Firebase events?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database

In the Firebase documents I am having trouble believing Google's own language Go doesn't support real-time events like `child_changed`

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

thier nodejs example:

```
ref.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
  var changedPost = snapshot.val();
  console.log("The updated post title is " + changedPost.title);
});
```

Has anyone written a function in Go to listen for these type of events?

Comment: Why would you think the official docs are inaccurate? And can you rephrase your question? As written it is off-topic for SO (request for recommendations of third-party resources).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Are you asking if Go supports `child_changed`?  Are you asking why it doesn't? Are you conducting a poll to see if others have noticed this problem? None of those questions are especially good ones. Maybe if you focus on "How to handle real-time events in Go" you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase documentation for [reading data with the admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) contains this:

> The Go Admin SDK currently only supports blocking reads. It cannot be used to add event listeners that receive realtime update notifications.

So it seems that the Go SDK does **not** support listening for updates.

If you really need such updates in your Go application, you can consider writing your own client for the [REST streaming API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-streaming) of the database, which fires REST SSE events.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [GetIfChanged](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/v4/db#Ref.GetIfChanged) method on db reference. But the catch is, that it sends the entire map on any field change. So you need to determine yourself what exactly has changed. Also it is slow while running in a continuous loop, due to network call in each loop.

```
    currEtag := "null_etag"
    
    //Continuos listening
    for {
        var latestData any
        ok, latestEtag, err := app.firebaseIn.GetDbRef("instruments").GetIfChanged().GetIfChanged(context.Background(), currEtag, &latestData)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if ok {
            // data has changed in db. use 'latestData' to do your stuff here...
            
            // updating the currEtag
            currEtag = latestEtag
        }
    }
```

*Etag is an identifier for a specific version of a resource.

Really hope someone to post a better solution.